# Facebook Interview Question: Formatting a collection of times for a movie show time output (using Linq is preferred)

Tags: c#, linq, facebook, date

```
class TimeObject
{
    DateTime time;
    bool isMatinee;
}

Given: {8:00, 9:30, 11:00, 12:10, 2:00, 4:00, 5:20} -- a collection of TimeObjects

Output: (8:00AM, 9:30, 11:00, 12:10PM, 2:00), 4:00, 5:20 -- return a string, oh and AM/PM should be picked up from localization strings

Caveats: AM/PM only shown for first time, ( ) encloses those elements whose matinee bool was set to true.
```

Question is: I have to figure out how to output the above string.

I mentioned, I knew C#, the interviewer was adamant to know how to do this in the fewest lines of readable code, preferably using LINQ. He said, I could write it to the console, but I had to remember to localize the AM and PM.

I obviously created a bunch of temp collections, and crap, and totally botched it up. He claims that it's only a few lines of LINQ. I tried other things, though he kept steering me towards LINQ.

Help? Any body has ideas? This has really been cringing me the whole day now.

**UPDATE** - I GOT THE JOB! They also asked me Edit distance {HELLO} --> {HLO}, tell the min. number of edits/updates it'll take to get to the final string. And there are Bees, And Honey in the world, there is 1 queen bee, the only way the honey can be accessed is through the Queen. Construct a make belief computer world that can support this, and tell if the world is in violation or not -- **Graph**, Root node is Queen Bee, Nodes are Honey and Bee, Run BiPartite test to see if world is in violation.

Comment: So what have got so far?

Comment: Nothing really, I thought of using a Stack, but meh, he didn't like it.

Comment: what do the brackets around the first lot of times in the output mean and why do only 2 times have am/pm beside them?

Comment: ( ) means that isMatinee was set to true for all those elements.

Comment: that's the whole programming problem, only the first am, and first pm get an am pm besides them.

Comment: Explanation of Matinée, for those who want to know (I think it's integral to the question (especially if you're British)): "An afternoon performance, starting before 7 pm. Occasionally a show will be performed twice nightly at, say, 7 and 9 pm. When this happens, the 7 pm show is sometimes referred to as the 'first house' rather than the matinee..."

Comment: You're at an interview for Facebook and they're asking C# questions? I thought Facebook was a PHP/Java shop? In any case, this is a cool interview question, I'll have to remember it for when I conduct my next interview.

Comment: Maybe the expected answer was just "I like it."

Comment: I didn't do Java in school. So he asked me this. This is a horrible interview question, I got the logic behind it in like 2 minutes, and kept fumbling in Linq land. Both the answers were where I was at, and couldn't progress to Linq.

I got the job though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[edit]
I'm sure there's a cleaner way to do this but here's what I have.  A simple grouping would make it easier if it weren't for the time formatting restrictions.  I'll try to come up with another version.

```
var amTimes = times.Where(to => to.time.Hour < 12)
                   .Select((to, i) => new
                   {
                       to.isMatinee,
                       repr = i == 0 ? to.time.ToString("h:mmtt")
                                     : to.time.ToString("h:mm")
                   });
var pmTimes = times.Where(to => to.time.Hour >= 12)
                   .Select((to, i) => new
                   {
                       to.isMatinee,
                       repr = i == 0 ? to.time.ToString("h:mmtt")
                                     : to.time.ToString("h:mm")
                   });
var stimes = amTimes.Concat(pmTimes);
var mats = String.Join(", ", stimes.Where(t => t.isMatinee).Select(t => t.repr));
var nonmats = String.Join(", ", stimes.Where(t => !t.isMatinee).Select(t => t.repr));

var output = string.Format("({0}), {1}", mats, nonmats);
```

---

[edit2]
Ok, so this is very likely THE kind of answer the interviewer was looking for.

```
var output = String.Join(", ",
    times.Select(to => new
    {
        prefix = to == times.First(t => t.isMatinee) ? "(" : "",
        time = to.time,
        fmt = to.time.Hour < 12
            ? (to == times.First(t => t.time.Hour < 12) ? "h:mmtt" : "h:mm")
            : (to == times.First(t => t.time.Hour >= 12) ? "h:mmtt" : "h:mm"),
        suffix = to == times.Last(t => t.isMatinee) ? ")" : "",
    })
    .Select(x => String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", x.prefix, x.time.ToString(x.fmt), x.suffix)));
```

Normally when I write LINQ expressions, I always try to consider the performance.  Since performance wasn't a factor here.  This should be the easiest to write and follow (but with horrible performance).

The approach, consider the time, how it's formatted, and any prefix (an open paren) or suffix (a closing paren) when printed.  As long as the `isMatinee` grouping is contiguous (which I had always assumed) with times sorted, this should always work.

It only has a prefix if it is the first time that is a matinee.  A suffix if it is the last time that is a matinee.  It should be formatted with AM/PM if it is the first time in its respective group.  It should be very easy to understand.

---

If it were only the matinee grouping involved, I'd probably do this:

```
var output = String.Join(", ",
    times.GroupBy(to => to.isMatinee, to => to.time.ToString("h:mm"))
         .Select(g => g.Key ? "(" + String.Join(", ", g) + ")"
                            : String.Join(", ", g)));
```

Comment: That is trivial, that is totally not my question. The question is to output the string like that. I've edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: I think IsMatinee would be populated in the initial list of objects. Considering that the times are not in 24 hr format, this flag would be used to determine whether it was an afternoon or (early) morning film.

Comment: Hmm... looks kinda alright. I still can't wrap my head around how the hell does it print PM and AM only once!

Comment: The idea I was having was that there are 2 ways to group this, by matinees and time of day.  The matinee group would be surrounded by parens while the time group has only a leading format.  Then to somehow superimpose these groups onto each other.  It's the superimposing that's making it difficult to do easily.

Comment: Hmm, Ok, so where is this "i" coming from? what does it mean? and what is repr?

Comment: There's an overload for `Select()` where the selector could take 2 parameters, the item (`to`) and its index (`i`) as it is iterated through.  It creates an anonymous object with 2 fields, `isMatinee` and `repr` which is the string representation of the time.

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer! Two last things

(1) would you do it the same way if you didn't have to do the ( ) markings for matinee.
(2) would you do it the same way if you didn't have to do leading am/pm for shows.

(1) and (2) are independent, to see how i can reduce verbosity if only one feature had to be implemented.

Comment: I'm wondering if you grouped by matinee if that would work ... I guess not. right?

Comment: If it was one format rule or the other, it would have been a lot easier IMO.  I'd probably use the same approach but could probably do it in a single (readable) expression.  Grouping by matinee was my first attempt, but the am/pm part made that harder to reason with.  I'll still try to find a cleaner way to do this because the idea seems so simple.

Comment: Would you mind posting solutions for if only matinee was asked? If only am/pm was asked, I get it - i would do it your way as it is now. But if it was only matinee, I'm still confused.

Comment: The reason I'm confused, because if i == 0, will give me the the left bracket, but how do I place the right bracket? After the string is constructed, I suppose? Meh ...

Comment: The actual parens are not inserted until the `string.Format()` at the very end.  `amTimes` and `pmTimes` were just the set of times in the AM or PM.  This makes writing only the leading AM/PM easier.  I have another approach to the problem which I'm writing up right now.  It should have been the most obvious answer which I'll explain as well as answer other questions you still have.

Comment: So this is worse performant than your previous one? Almost does look like what the interviewer would have wanted though.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool AMShown = false;
bool PMShown = false;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

//assuming it groups with false first:
foreach(var timeObjGrp in collection.GroupBy(p=>p.isMatinee))
{
    if (grpTimeObj.Key) StringBuilder.Append("(");
    foreach (var timeObjItem in timeObjGrp)
    {
        StringBuilder.Append(timeObjItem.time.ToString("h:m"));
        //IsAM should be something like Hours < 12
        if (!AMShown && timeObjItem.time.IsAM)
        {
            StringBuilder.Append("AM");
            AMShown = true;
        }
        if (!PMShown && timeObjItem.time.IsPM)
        {
            StringBuilder.Append("PM");
            PMShown = true;
        }
        StringBuilder.Append(",");
    }
    //here put something to remove last comma
    if (grpTimeObj.Key) StringBuilder.Append(")");
    StringBuilder.Append(",");
}
//here put something to remove last comma
```

I'm not sure it's LINQ-ish enough but it's readable

Comment: The reason to use LINQ is to avoid having state information like AMShown, PMShown.

I'm still trying to wrap my head around the others' solution, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
var output =
    String.Join(", ",
        from g in given
        orderby g.time
        group g by g.time.Hour < 12 into ggs
        select
            String.Join(", ", ggs.Select((x, n) =>
            {
                var template = n == 0 ? "{0:h:mmtt}" : "{0:h:mm}";
                template = x.isMatinee ? String.Format("({0})", template) : template;
                return String.Format(template, x.time);
            }).ToArray())
    ).Replace("), (", ", ");
```

(The assumption here is that the times are only for a single day.)

---

**@halivingston**

To answer your questions:

Q1. How the query works.

- The outer `String.Join` is used, as you rightly say, to join together all of the individual formatted times into a single string.
- Since Linq is functional in nature it is easier to compute each element independently from the rest so I bracket every matinee time. This introduces redundant bracketing around the formatted times which are removed by the `Replace` function.
- The Linq query orders the `TimeObject` instances by `time` (as we don't know if they are necessarily in order when we get the collection) and then it groups them by a boolean value where `true` is "AM" and `false` is "PM". The variable `ggs` is the group that gets created and is named as such by my convention of calling it a "group of g's".
- Each group contains an `IEnumerable<TimeObject>` which needs to be iterated over to build each formatted string. However we need to differentiate between the first element and the remaining elements so we need to use the `Select` overload that provides the element and the index of the element. Once we have that we can build up a `String.Format` template that will correctly add AM/PM to the first element and also add brackets to **each** matinee element.
- `String.Join` is again used to concatenate the individual elements into a single string. The result is that the Linq query returns an `IEnumerable<string>` with two elements. (The outer `String.Join` turns these into the final single string.)

Q2. To allow for times to span multiple days I would make the following change:

```
group g by g.time.Date.AddHours(g.time.Hour < 12 ? 0.0 : 12:00) into ggs
```

This will allow any number of days to be grouped together while still separating AM and PM.

I hope that this helps.

Comment: Let me try this. I understand the outer String.Join is just concating the whole thing. The inner one is a bit hard to follow. What is ggs? What is the last replace for?

Comment: Ok, if I have a list for multiple days, how will I modify this code? It seems like I'll have to strip the list of it, seems the easiest.

Comment: I wish I could also mark yours as answer, it's really more neat than the other, except the other made me understand more. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

I'd hardly call this short (and readable), but it's almost all LINQ at least:

```
            var outputGroups =
                from item in given
                let needSuffix =
                    object.ReferenceEquals(item, given.FirstOrDefault(to => to.Time.Hour < 12)) ||
                    object.ReferenceEquals(item, given.FirstOrDefault(to => to.Time.Hour >= 12))
                let suffix = needSuffix ? "tt" : string.Empty // could use AM/PM from resources instead of DateTime format string
                let timeFormat = string.Format("H:mm{0}", suffix)
                group item.Time.ToString(timeFormat) by item.IsMatinee into matineeGroup
                orderby matineeGroup.Key descending
                let items = string.Join(", ", matineeGroup.ToArray())
                let format = matineeGroup.Key ? "({0})" : "{0}"
                select string.Format(format, items);

            var result = string.Join(", ", outputGroups.ToArray());
```